# How can I run the original command that I also have aliased with same name?

Tags: command-line, bash, alias

I have an alias for the `ls` command in my `~/.bashrc` file aliased with this one:

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

When I run the `ls` command in a terminal, the aliased `ls` (`ls --color=auto`) runs.

My question is: how can I run the original `ls` only (not the aliased one), without any extra arguments and without deleting the aliased entry?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can bypass aliases by the following methods:

1. the full pathname of the command: `/bin/ls`
2. command substitution: `$(which ls)`
3. the command builtin: `command ls`
4. double quotation marks: `"ls"`
5. single quotation marks: `'ls'`
6. a backslash character: `\ls`

Comment: additional precisions in bash : `command something` bypasses both **alias** AND **function** named `something`. `\\something`, `'something'` and `"something"` only bypasses **alias** named `something` (if a function exist, it will then be called). (alias precede function if both exist and none are bypassed)

Answer (score 13):

You can disable an alias using `\` in front of command.

So to run the original `ls` command you need to run it using `\ls`

**For example**

- First creating alias of `ls` command.

  ```
  [guru@guru-Aspire-5738 /]$ alias ls='ls -l'
  [guru@guru-Aspire-5738 /]$ ls
  total 96
  drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Sep  3 18:31 bin
  drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Sep 17 02:51 boot
  drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Sep  3 22:17 cdrom
  drwxr-xr-x  17 root root  4520 Sep 17 21:11 dev
  drwxr-xr-x 153 root root 12288 Sep 17 21:11 etc
  drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Sep  3 22:17 home
  lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    37 Sep  8 21:31 initrd.img -> /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-68-generic-pae
  lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    36 Sep  3 22:18 initrd.img.old -> boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-
  ```

  (and many more...)
- Output of  original `ls` using `\` which  override the alias.

  ```
  [guru@guru-Aspire-5738 /]$ \ls
  bin    etc         lib     opt   sbin     tmp      vmlinuz.old
  boot   home        lost+found  proc  selinux  usr
  cdrom  initrd.img      media       root  srv      var
  dev    initrd.img.old  mnt     run   sys      vmlinuz
  [guru@guru-Aspire-5738 /]$
  ```

Answer (score 11):

### Suspend alias expansion

You could also disable alias expansion for all aliases temporarily, without deleting them:

```
$ shopt -u expand_aliases
$ command -v ls
/bin/ls
```

To enable them:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
$ command -v ls
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

Note that alias expansion is disabled by default in scripts, but set by default in interactive shells.

Answer (score 7):

You could add `command` before the aliased command, e.g.

```
command ls
```

Or run the original executable by combining `which`

```
which ls
```

It will return `/bin/ls`, therefore with

```
`which ls`
```

or

```
$(which ls)
```

you could execute that file directly.

Answer (score 6):

You can also run the command from its original location `/bin/ls` instead of `ls`