# ls vs. ls -C difference

Tags: command-line, ls

commands `ls` and `ls -C` seem to produce the same results - display by columns.

Is there any difference?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Referring to `info coreutils 'ls invocation'`:

> `-C'` --format=vertical'
>
> List files in columns, sorted vertically.  **This is the default for
> ls if standard output is a terminal**.  It is always the default for the dir program.  GNU ls uses variable width columns to display as many files as possible in the fewest lines.

**TL;DR**: no, no difference - that's default.

Comment: **if standard output is a terminal** ... now compare `ls > ls.txt` and `ls -C > lsC.txt`

Comment: @R.M. if your point is to say that `ls > ls.txt` and `ls -C > lsC.txt` output just one column to a file . . . well , you're right !  The single column ( or `-1`  flag ) is default output for file, which is what's happening with `ls > ls.txt`. With `ls -C > lsC.txt` you're missing something - the width , `-w` or `--width=COLS` flag. When in terminal , width is automatically determined from the widths of your screen, but how does ls know width of a file ? It doesnt !  Try this: `ls -C -w 300 > lsC2.txt `

Comment: @Serg, you actually answered another question I had in mind (why text in some files overflows on low res screen). Thanks man.

Comment: @Serg Interesting ... on my machine `ls -C > lsC.txt` makes multiple column output (for a ~80 character width, it looks like), whereas `ls > ls.txt` is a single column.  -- But my main point was that the '-C' option is not superfluous, and has a purpose when redirecting the output (i.e. when the output is not a terminal), and that "no, no difference" between with/without -C only applies to certain situations.

Comment: @R.M. what's your system and `ls --version` , by the way ?

Comment: @Serg - Xubuntu 14.04; ls (GNU coreutils) 8.21; I just checked, and I see the same behavior on CentOS 6.6 with ls version 8.4.

Answer (score 0):

read the output of `alias`
your ls command is in probably doing `ls -CF`.
It may be set in your bash_rc file too.
so `ls -F` will also give the same output.

but you could change it, in which case, you might want it. 
OR you could use it in a script, and maybe you want that style of output.

Comment: Apropos: http://askubuntu.com/questions/525231/how-can-i-run-original-command-that-aliased-with-same-name (Assuming bash)

Comment: alias ls='ls --color=auto' only in my Ubuntu 14.04. Apparently it's just system default as Serg said above.