# alias for command-line options not recognized

Tags: command-line, bash, alias

I have few flags I want to add to my gcc compilation, so I `alias`ed them as

```
alias gcc_flags='-std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -Wconversion'
```

and tried to compile like this:

```
$ gcc gcc_flags file_name.c -o object_name -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lcurl
gcc: error: gcc_flags: No such file or directory
```

When compiling without the alias, i.e.

```
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic file_name.c -o object_name -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lcurl
```

the compilation works just fine. Why is that?

---

- `gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4`
- `alias gcc_flags='-std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -Wconversion'` appears on my alias list
- Ubuntu version - `Release:        14.04`

---

By the way, isn't it about time for `gcc` to compile with `-std=c99` by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Aliases  allow a string to be substituted for a word when it is used
>    **as the first word** of a simple command. (`man bash`, emphasis mine)

To create an alias for `gcc` with custom flags, do it like so instead:

```bsh
alias gcc_flags='gcc -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -Wconversion'
```

And run your command as:

```bsh
gcc_flags file_name.c -o object_name -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lcurl
```

---

If there are options you keep adding every time and feel should be default, you can also add an alias for `gcc` itself, e.g.:

```bsh
alias gcc='gcc -std=c99'
```

This way `gcc` will always be started with that flag. If you then want to ignore the `alias` and use it *without* that flag you can run it as `\gcc` or in a number of different ways listed in [How can I run original command that aliased with same name?](https://askubuntu.com/q/525231/507051).