# How to replace apt with nala?

Tags: command-line, apt, nala

I love [`nala`](https://github.com/volitank/nala) and I want to use it, but my muscle memory always goes for `apt` and every guide on the internet uses `apt` when I copy paste commands.

Is there a way where, even if I type `apt`, `nala` is still used?

Answer (score 5):

You can create new aliases for both the `apt` and `nala` commands like this:

```
alias apt='\nala'
alias dapt='\apt'
```

The backslash character preceding the commands disable alias expansion, so you can rename commands, but still run the originals ([see here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525231/how-can-i-run-original-command-that-aliased-with-same-name)).

In addition, for aliases to work with `sudo`, you need to add this alias also ([see here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22037/aliases-not-available-when-using-sudo)):

```
alias sudo='sudo '
```

Just be aware that if you copy and paste `apt` commands from the internet, that you now run with `nala`, it's possible that some options are not supported. So be sure to check it's a valid command for `nala` before you run it.

Answer (score 0):

You should never *never* alias system commands, especially as `root`. If you want to run `nala`, then just run `nala`.

You can alias `sudo` to `sudo`  and `apt` and/or `apt-get` to `\nala`, but it is likely not a good idea to do this because something can break.